# General log of MySQL server show a record " query rollback" after inserting to table , but record still there in table

Tags: mysql

General log of MySQL server show a record " query rollback" after inserting to table , but record still there in table. Can any one  explain what happened here.

Inserted a sale transaction to table called transactions table. The log shows as follow

```
2018-09-12T04:17:34.215985Z    14 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
2018-09-12T04:17:37.223987Z    14 Query SHOW GLOBAL STATUS
2018-09-12T04:17:38.565372Z    29 Connect   root@localhost on nevro using TCP/IP
2018-09-12T04:17:38.565796Z    29 Query /* mysql-connector-java-8.0.12 (Revision: 24766725dc6e017025532146d94c6e6c488fb8f1) */SELECT  @@session.auto_increment_increment AS auto_increment_increment, @@character_set_client AS character_set_client, @@character_set_connection AS character_set_connection, @@character_set_results AS character_set_results, @@character_set_server AS character_set_server, @@collation_server AS collation_server, @@init_connect AS init_connect, @@interactive_timeout AS interactive_timeout, @@license AS license, @@lower_case_table_names AS lower_case_table_names, @@max_allowed_packet AS max_allowed_packet, @@net_write_timeout AS net_write_timeout, @@sql_mode AS sql_mode, @@system_time_zone AS system_time_zone, @@time_zone AS time_zone, @@transaction_isolation AS transaction_isolation, @@wait_timeout AS wait_timeout
2018-09-12T04:17:38.566227Z    29 Query SET NAMES utf8mb4
2018-09-12T04:17:38.566388Z    29 Query SET character_set_results = NULL
2018-09-12T04:17:38.566568Z    29 Query SET autocommit=1
2018-09-12T04:17:38.566791Z    29 Query SET autocommit=0
2018-09-12T04:17:38.568687Z    29 Query insert into transactions (ID,CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,CUSTOMER_TYPE,PAYMENT_TYPE,TRANSACTION_DATE,USER,USER_NAME,TOTAL_VALUE,TIME,CANCEL) values(0,9999,'GUEST CUSTOMER','GUEST','Cash','2018-09-12',100007,'Nick',1940.0,'09:47:38',0)
2018-09-12T04:17:38.570476Z    29 Query commit
2018-09-12T04:17:38.682805Z    29 Query rollback
2018-09-12T04:17:38.682990Z    29 Quit
```

Even though it is roll back ( 2018-09-12T04:17:38.682805Z      29 Query rollback ) relevant record exist in the table.

Please explain this what exactly happened here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rollback` is preceded by a `commit`. A rollback "undoes" only *un*-committed changes.

That is, the `commit` finalized the changes; when the `rollback` was issued, there weren't any uncommitted changes to rollback.